# facets with ravendb

Tags: ravendb

i am trying to work with the facet ability in ravendb but getting strange results.

i have a documents like :

```
 {
  "SearchableModel": "42LC2RR ",
  "ModelName": "42LC2RR",
  "ModelID": 490578,
  "Name": "LG 42 Television 42LC2RR",
  "Desctription": "fffff",
  "Image": "1/4/9/8/18278941c",
  "MinPrice": 9400.0,
  "MaxPrice": 9400.0,
  "StoreAmounts": 1,
  "AuctionAmounts": 0,
  "Popolarity": 3,
  "ViewScore": 0.0,
  "ReviewAmount": 2,
  "ReviewScore": 45,
  "Sog": "E-TV",
  "SogID": 1,
  "IsModel": true,
  "Manufacrurer": "LG",
  "ParamsList": [
    "1994267",
    "46570",
    "4134",
    "4132",
    "4118",
    "46566",
    "4110",
    "180676",
    "239517",
    "750771",
    "2658507",
    "2658498",
    "46627",
    "4136",
    "169941",
    "169846",
    "145620",
    "169940",
    "141416",
    "3190767",
    "3190768",
    "144720",
    "2300706",
    "4093",
    "4009",
    "1418470",
    "179766",
    "190025",
    "170557",
    "170189",
    "43768",
    "4138",
    "67976",
    "239516",
    "3190771",
    "141195"
  ],
}
```

where the ParamList each represents a property of the product and in our application we have in cache what each param represents.

when searching for a specific product i would like to count all the returning attributes to be able to add the amount of each item after the search.

After searching lg in televisions category i want to get :

Param:4134 witch is a representative of LCD and the amount :65.

but unfortunately i am getting strange results. only some params are counted and some not. 
on some searchers where i am getting results back i dont get any amounts back.

i am using the latest stable version of RavenDB.

index :

```
from doc in docs
from param in doc.ParamsList
select new {Name=doc.Name,Description=doc.Description,SearchNotVisible = doc.SearchNotVisible,SogID=doc.SogID,Param =param}
```

facet :

```
 DocumentStore documentStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "Server" };
        documentStore.Initialize();
        using (IDocumentSession session = documentStore.OpenSession())
        {
            List<Facet> _facets = new List<Facet>
                        {
                            new Facet {Name = "Param"}

                        };

            session.Store(new FacetSetup { Id = "facets/Params", Facets = _facets });
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
```

usage example :

```
IDictionary<string, IEnumerable<FacetValue>> facets = session.Advanced.DatabaseCommands.GetFacets("FullIndexParams", new IndexQuery { Query = "Name:lg" }, "facets/Params");
```

i tried many variations without success.

does anyone have ideas what am i doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this index, it should resolve your problem:

```
from doc in docs
select new {Name=doc.Name,Description=doc.Description,SearchNotVisible = doc.SearchNotVisible,SogID=doc.SogID,Param = doc.ParamsList}
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this option before posting . but unfortunately also didn't work for me .

Answer (score 0):

What analyzer you set for "Name" field. I see you search by Name "lg". By default, Ravendb use KeywordAnalyzer, means you must search by exact name. You should set another analyzer for Name or Description field (StandardAnalyzer for example).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19553384)

Comment: @EndangeredMassa "You should set another analyzer for Name..." In my opinion this provides a possible answer to the question. The first sentence can and probably should be removed though indeed.

Comment: Sorry. He only provides the Map property of the index, so I don't know his all index config. I'd just want to comment to him but I'm new and do not have enough reputation point to do that ^^! will notice this next time.